# What is a word that describes "to trudge through" a liquid but for milk?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I am talking about Words like "bemire" and "daggle".
I want a word verb that describes the act being sludged/dragged/ran through milk, and the noun for the soiled object in that situation, what would it be called?

Comment: How often does that happen for there to be an accepted word for it? The soiled object is perhaps 'milk-sodden' but asking for a noun for an object saturated in milk is a tall order. Looking at 'trudge through milk', the verb 'trudge' implies some distance of travel. It's hard to even envisage the situation described.

Comment: **run** is the  standard past participle, "being run", not "being ran".

Comment: Would that word need to work for trudging through soy milk, almond milk, or goat's milk just as well as trudging through cow's milk? And what about skim milk and chocolate milk?

Comment: Milk is not particularly viscous. You’d be wet, but I’m not sure where you want to go with a  verb — let alone a noun — for that.

Comment: *dunked Oreo* … *milksop* means something else now.

Comment: *milky* is an adjective but doesn't imply being bedraggled or sodden. Generally used of colour or tea/coffee.

Comment: Also, question is confused. To trudge through something is not the same as being dragged through it. What exact action are you referring to?

Comment: If you wanted someone to speed up, 'shake a leg' is available.

Comment: See [Is there a verb for "walking slowly into water"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/336901/191178)

Answer (score 1):

When you do it with food - first into milk, then into breading - it's called 'dredging.'

M-W supplies:

> [dredge](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dredge)
>
> 3 of 3
> verb (2)
> dredged; dredging
>
> transitive verb
>
> : to coat by sprinkling (as with flour)
>
>  *dredge* the chicken in flour
>
> The fish is *dredged* with a cornmeal mixture and fried.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).